# create a query for date and average values

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I need to select date and average values from a datacontext's table and I need to group it by year and by month.
In SQL it will look like this

```
select Year(data) as years, Month(data) as months, Avg(value) as prices from Prices
group by Year(data),MONTH(data)
order by years, months
```

I've created a LINQ query

```
var query0 = from c in dc.Prices
             where Convert.ToDateTime(c.data).CompareTo(left) >= 0
                   && Convert.ToDateTime(c.data).CompareTo(right) <= 0
                   && c.idsticker.Equals(x)
              group c by new { ((DateTime)c.data).Year, ((DateTime)c.data).Month }
                    into groupMonthAvg
              select groupMonthAvg;
```

But I don't know how to get average values in result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Average function.

```
var query0 = from c in dc.Prices
             where Convert.ToDateTime(c.data).CompareTo(left) >= 0
                   && Convert.ToDateTime(c.data).CompareTo(right) <= 0
                   && c.idsticker.Equals(x)
              group c by new { ((DateTime)c.data).Year, ((DateTime)c.data).Month }
                    into groupMonthAvg
              select new
              {
                  years = groupMonthAvg.Key.Year,
                  months = groupMonthAvg.Key.Month,
                  prices = groupMonthAvg.Average(x=>x.value)
              };
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [Average](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.average.aspx) function in your `select`:

```
var query0 = from c in dc.Prices
         where Convert.ToDateTime(c.data).CompareTo(left) >= 0
               && Convert.ToDateTime(c.data).CompareTo(right) <= 0
               && c.idsticker.Equals(x)
          group c by new { ((DateTime)c.data).Year, ((DateTime)c.data).Month }
                into groupMonthAvg
          select new {
              groupMonthAvg.Key.Year, 
              groupMonthAvg.Key.Month, 
              YearAverage = groupMonthAvg.Average(x=>x.Year),
              MonthAverage = groupMonthAvg.Average(x=>x.Month)
              };
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var query0 = from c in dc.Prices
             where Convert.ToDateTime(c.data).CompareTo(left) >= 0
                   && Convert.ToDateTime(c.data).CompareTo(right) <= 0
                   && c.idsticker.Equals(x)
              group c by new { ((DateTime)c.data).Year, ((DateTime)c.data).Month }
                    into groupMonthAvg
              select new { Year = groupMonthAvg.Key.Year, Month = groupMonthAvg.Key.Month, Average => groupMonthAvg.Average(i => i.value) };
```